# Build causing java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Many seem to face this problem on Stackoverflow but non had the same problem and solution as I did.

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class"

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hey"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

I had this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/collections/Buffer;

I fixed it using `multiDexEnabled true` but then the duplicate entry error showed up.

EDIT:

The problem was with `commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1` but I'm still curious onto why and how to fix this error to still be able to use the validator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested I solved the problem by replacing:

`compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'`

with:

`compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'`